# Magnetic force of a magnetic field around a wire

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

Suppose we have a magnetic field around a wire because there goes a current through the wire. Suppose there are not any magnets near. Is it ture that there is then also a magnetic force?

If so, is it true that we may deduce the direction of $B$ using the right-hand rule and the direction of the magnetic force $F$ using the left-hand rule?

Comment: What do you mean "magnetic force"? You mean that, absent external magnetic fields, the wire experiences a force due to the magnetic field it is generating?

Comment: @DanielGriscom Basically, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Whenever a current passes through a wire, a magnetic field is induced; Whenever a magnetic field passes over a wire, a current is induced... and it's a yes to your second question too.